# C# - Accesing to items for a collection inherited from List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I am trying to implement a new class inherited from `List<string>`, to load the contents from a text file to the items.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class ListExt : List<string>
{
    string baseDirectory;

    public void LoadFromFile(string FileName)
    {
        //does not work because _list is private
        this._items = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).ToList();
    }
}
```

But I dont know how to load the lines into the `_items` property because it is private.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, LoadFromFile must have void

Comment: Sounds like you want an extension method, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ListExt` *is* the list - so you can just call `AddRange` on yourself. You can't *reassign* the list - that would essentially be changing `this`.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like:

```
public void LoadFromFile(string FileName)
{
    base.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FileName));
}
```

Comment: Changed it a bit after thinking about it... :)

Comment: Why `base.AddRange` instead of `this.AddRange`?

Comment: Depends on what you want. Sometimes you have implemented a bit more checks etc on the new method that you do not want to call. I know both this and base works here but I think he was going for a pure add and then base is sometimes better. But then again, it does not matter in this case

Answer (score 1):

No need to derive a whole new class from `List<T>` over the following line.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FileName).ToList());
```

Comment: The ToList() is a waste of memory, an array is an IEnumerable aswell.